# .htaccess redirect conflict with other code in file?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to alter my `.htaccess` file so when URL `https://www.metaalboutique.nl/Contactformulier` is used page `https://www.metaalboutique.nl/contact_form.php` is shown.

Is there some code in my `.htaccess` file that is conflicting with this and that might be the reason that this is not working?

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.metaalboutique.nl$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.metaalboutique.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^metaalboutique\.nl$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Redirect 301 /closed/index.php    https://www.metaalboutique.nl

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?metaalboutique.nl [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]

RewriteRule ^Contactformulier$ contact_form.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Rule `RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` rewrites everything that is not a directory to `php`  . This also matches `/Contactformulier` and rewrites it to `/Contactformulier.php` . You can either remove this rule from your htaccess or use the following modified version of your htaccess .

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

Redirect 301 /closed/index.php    https://www.metaalboutique.nl/

RewriteEngine on
#redirect http to https and non-www in a single redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^metaalboutique.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.metaalboutique.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
#deny access to remote referers
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?metaalboutique.nl [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
#access .php files without using extension
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
#rewrite /Contactformulier to /contact_form.php
 RewriteRule ^Contactformulier$ contact_form.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this .